# How to have archive command from stand by to stand by ( scp ) for database replication. ( Note : Not from master to stand by. )

Tags: postgresql, database-replication, postgresql-9.6

Actually I have a quite large setup for a project. Which has 4 database servers in IDC setup and 3 database servers in DR setup. I have one primary server I will replicate data as wal file though streaming and scp to 3 IDC and 1 DR setup database servers. As I have a backup support ( Archive Command ) scp if streaming is stopped for this 1 DR setup and 3 IDC setup. But I don't know whether postgresql have an option of having backup support of archive command for stand by to stand by for replication in DR setup ? If so can it hold the wal file from deleting in primary or in the 1 DR setup server which gets wal file from my primary ? If there are alternatives other than repmgr or support for the feature. In short, whether we can have archive command  while in cascading in DR setup or not ? [ If yes, whether that will prevent wal files from deleting ? If yes, it will prevent in primary or standby ] / [ If not, whether there is alternatives other than repmgr ]. As most  times my setup's streaming is getting stopped. So archiving is the way I can prevent from deleting the wal file which has to be available for recovering.  Kindly let me know if there is a way.

Comment: I'm not sure to have well understood what you wanted, but it seems to me like cascading replication... If I'm right, you'll find every information you need in the documentation : https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/warm-standby.html#CASCADING-REPLICATION

Comment: Arkhena can you please eloborate about warm standby. Actually with that article I ain't able to connect to my scenario.